# Mac OSX 10.11.15 SpringBoard quit unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am running Mac OSX 10.11.15
Tested with XCode 7.3 and 7.3.1

I am compiling my iOS application on the mac and the target is an iOS Simulator running iOS 9.3. Given some time (5-10 minutes) i will get the following error.

[SpringBoard has quit unexpectedly](http://pastebin.com/b8ZPqG9q)

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Set breakpoints in around the place your code crashes; looks like something to do with an alarm, or calendar.

Comment: @The application doesn't use either. It also happens with other applications i have that also don't have either so i can't set breakpoints.

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug with `OS X` and something you should report to Apple.

Comment: I already did, doesn't do me much good in the meantime. I have two Macs, one that is 6 years old and a new one i just purchased. The old one is fine, the new one is experiencing this issue. I cannot find a cause for it since they both have all the same versioning in the software.

Comment: Maybe try re-installing Xcode on the one that's crashing, or at the very least re-install the simulators for it.

Comment: I already tried to reinstall XCode several times from itunes store or through the dmg, how do i reinstall just the simulators?

Comment: The simulator SDK is located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk`. You could likely remove it and then from within Xcode Preferences > Components > Simulators download them again. You could also check and see if there's any difference in the Xcode / SDKs between each of your machines.

Comment: One other thing you might try first is to reset the simulator settings on the one that is crashing. ("iOS Simulator" > "Reset Content and Settings..." )

Comment: I did that as well several times :( I have not tried reinstalling the simulators themselves though and that does sound like a good attempt. How would i go about that?

Comment: I mentioned how [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335227/mac-osx-10-11-15-springboard-quit-unexpectedly?noredirect=1#comment64087891_38335227), two comments ago.

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't see that comment. I'll try that and update. There is also no difference between the two machines except for the hardware. and OS X version. Older machine uses 10.11.1 and newer machine uses 10.11.15. I tried XCode 7.3 on both and 7.3.1 on both. It works regardless on the old machine and breaks on the new one with the Spring Error. It has me stumped that i'm almost going to format the machine or return it for a new one. I can't trace it since it's not application specific or machine specific.

Comment: Can't remove it, it doesn't appear in the download list later and i can only download 9.2, even though I removed 9.3. Furthermore, the newly downloaded simulators don't go into that folder, I'm not quite sure where they go, xcode doesn't detect it and won't compile or run the project into the newly downloaded 9.2 simulator. Only way to get 9.3 back is to reinstall xcode *sigh* :(

Comment: You want to download the SDK.